# GridView Template Column hiddenfield value is always 0 while visibility false

Tags: asp.net

I have GridView with Template Column.Inside the template column i have asp:hiddenfield. I am binding the value using Eval() method.When i am trying to access the value of hiddenfi not accesible while visibility false
**ASPX**

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" Visible="false">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnMasterId" runat="server" 
              Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Master_Id") %>' />
           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
       </ItemTemplate>
       <ItemStyle Width="4%" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
protected void gdvList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int intIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow row = gdvList.Rows[intIndex];
    HiddenField hdn = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hdnMasterId");
}
```

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: @ Mansoor Gee:-When i am trying to access the hiddenfield value its always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set visibility="false" on a column it won't generate any html, thus wont have the hidden control. You need to put the hiddenfield elsewhere or hide the column with css/style instead.

Comment: :-Thanks for the reply...Whether the Same can be obtain by using asp:Label control?

Comment: How do you mean? A Label will convert into a div tag and won't post anything back.

Comment: i have added a label inside the templete column,its visibility false,now binding the text with the Master_Id.Now in the row_command i am getting the text value.

Comment: I guess that is because the labels text is stored in the ViewState. If your try to change it with javascript you won't get the changes back to the server though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try as:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 string strValue = ((HiddenField)GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[cellindex].FindControl("HiddenFieldID")).Value;
}
```